# WP8 Sending JSON to Server

Tags: json, post, windows-phone-8

I am trying to POST some JSON data to my Server. I am using simple code which I have attained from: [Http Post for Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698879/http-post-for-windows-phone-8)

Code:

```
        string url = "myserver.com/path/to/my/post";

        // HTTP web request
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        // Write the request Asynchronously 
        using (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream,
                                                                 httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream, null))
        {
            //create some json string
            string json = "{ \"my\" : \"json\" }";

            // convert json to byte array
            byte[] jsonAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            // Write the bytes to the stream
            await stream.WriteAsync(jsonAsBytes, 0, jsonAsBytes.Length);
        }
```

I am getting an error though on `await` and `Task`:

[image]

Anyone see the obvious error?

Comment: yes, look at the error messages. Did you decorate the method with the  "async" word?

Comment: I changed the method signature to:         [Async]
        public Task ReportSighting(Sighting sighting) But i get Async could not be found

Comment: async and not [A]sync, keywords are case sensitive in C#

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing method signature to:

public async Task ReportSighting(Sighting sighting)