# Http GET request from windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

This code works on windows forms :

```
string URI = "http://localhost/1/index.php?dsa=232323";
string myParameters = "";

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
}
```

But i want to send http GET request from windows phone 8 . in wp 8 there are no methods `UploadString()` and etc...

Comment: You want to send `http GET`  but use UploadString?

Comment: UploadString is deleted methond in windows phone 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using(HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await hc.PostAsync(url,new StringContent (yourString));
}
```

And for your case, you can upload `FormUrlEncodedContent` content instead of forming upload string manually.

```
using(HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
{
    var keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    // Fill keyValuePairs

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValuePairs);

    var response = await hc.PostAsync(url, content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [HTTP Client NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.2.18) library. It works for me in Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

For GET method you can give the strings along with the URI itself.

```
private void YourCurrentMethod()
{
    string URI = "http://localhost/1/index.php?dsa=232323";
    string myParameters = "";

    URI = URI + "&" + myParameters; 

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URI);

    request.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    request.BeginGetResponse(GetResponseCallback, request);
}

void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
    if (request != null)
    {
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
            //Do what you want with this response
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Already answered here: [Http Post for Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698879/http-post-for-windows-phone-8) -- you will want something like this:

```
// server to POST to
string url = "myserver.com/path/to/my/post";

// HTTP web request
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

// Write the request Asynchronously 
using (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream,          
                                                         httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream, null))
{
   //create some json string
   string json = "{ \"my\" : \"json\" }";

   // convert json to byte array
   byte[] jsonAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

   // Write the bytes to the stream
   await stream.WriteAsync(jsonAsBytes, 0, jsonAsBytes.Length);
}
```