# Sending POST request to a web server in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, webservice-client, restsharp, c#-5.0

I am making a Windows Phone 8 application where I need to send login credentials to web server(I am using **RESTSHARP**) and post authentication (response) , I have to do variety of tasks.
I was using the following code base but I am getting **Not Acceptable** error message.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://com.example");

                var request = new RestRequest("/REsource/", Method.POST);

               // Json to post 


                request.AddParameter("username", userName.Text);
                request.AddParameter("password", Password.Text);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
                                if (response != null && ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && 
                                 (response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Completed))) // It's probably not necessary to test both
                                   {

                                   }
                               else if (response != null)
                                 {
                                MessageBox.Show(string.Format
                        ("Status code is {0} ({1}); response status is {2}",
                               response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription, response.ResponseStatus));
                    }  
                });
```

I tried **HTTPResponseMessage** part of **HTTPCLient** also and but dont know how to send a **POST** .

Comment: Hi Apporv, Here is a good link to refer for simple POST in WP. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14698947/2549049

Comment: @Apoorv , try this also [.NET HttpClient. How to POST string value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176538/net-httpclient-how-to-post-string-value)

Comment: ACtually I am looking on the RESTSHARP Library for doing this !! The above methods hold fine

Comment: Does `request.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(userName.Text, Password.Text);` help?